# Allow a node to have many dates attached to it

Tags: nodes, entities, datetime

I am stumped trying to figure out how to set up a node to have many dates attached to it without having to just add a lot of date fields to it.

The scenario is that we have a show, and that show occurs on multiple days at different or multiple times each day.

I'd like to be able to have a content type of 'Show' with *a* date field and then just add multiple dates to it. However, the Date field doesn't seem to support multiple values.

How do I make this work?

Comment: Turns out the answer is relatively simple - as long as you don't choose a Widget for the Date field that handles repeating dates, the 'Number of Values' field appears and you can choose 'Unlimited'.

So choosing:
Select List with Repeat options; or
Text Field with Date Pop-up and Repeat options.

will not allow you to have multiple values. Any other options should be OK.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Just answering this myself so it doesn't count towards the unanswered total.*

Turns out the answer is relatively simple - as long as you don't choose a Widget for the Date field that handles repeating dates, the 'Number of Values' field appears and you can choose 'Unlimited'.

So choosing either of the following Widget types:

- Select List with Repeat options; or
- Text Field with Date Pop-up and Repeat options

will not allow you to have multiple values. Any other options should be OK.

Answer (score 2):

[Office hours](http://drupal.org/project/office_hours) is a module that can help you. It's built for entering complex opening hours for a physical place. It minded for a per week display, but it does support some custom entries, by entering week numbers but this is not well docented

I'm not sure how well it will work for your case, but it can at least give you a head start.

Comment: Thanks googletorp - a good suggestion but I've managed to get the default Date field to do what I need.

Comment: @marblegravy Can you please post your solution of Date field? Thanks

Comment: @PreritMohan - See the accepted answer above. That's how I solved it.